# Pass parameter out from Ext.window.Window to an Ext.panel.Panel on close

Tags: extjs, reference, window, extjs5

I have a main window with a custom `Ext.panel.Panel` using ExtJS 5.0.1.

Clicking an item shown on the custom panel creates and shows a custom `Ext.window.Window` for editing said item.

For the purpose of getting some kind of answer, or a starting point for my own situation, I'll ask for standard Ext components.

On closing the custom window, a variable in the custom panel needs to be updated to show that changes have been made.

This is a different requirement to a confirmation message before closing the window; the window does not control saving of information to a DB, but needs to let another component know that changes have been made.

This should be as simple as setting a boolean `unsavedChanges` to `true` on the panel if the window's information has been altered; I've performed this on a simpler page, which did not have the additional window as an obstacle.

Due to the use of the window, my typical go-to methods of calculating a variable as use of `this.up` or `this.lookupReference` returns null, or throw an error.

I'm aware that I can consider going to the parent of the page, then try and work down, but I'm not experienced enough to consolidate standard javaScript with the `up` and `down` capabilities of ExtJS, or at least understand the intricacies of ExtJS to navigate past the "item window" back to the panel.

How would I be able to refer to the panel while closing the window in order to update the panel's data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there's a couple of ways.

First, you can pass in your panel, or a callback function, during the construction of the window. e.g.:

```
// in panel
var window = Ext.create('MyWindow', { callingPanel: this })
```

...

```
// in window
onClose: function() { this.callingPanel.doStuff(); }
```

The other way to be to register a listener to the 'close' event of the window.

```
// in panel
var window = Ext.create('MyWindow', {
  listeners: {
    scope: this,
    close: this.doStuff
  }
})
```

The listener approach tends to work best when you don't want to tightly couple the window to the calling panel.